# Query to find out if the year is a leap year using a simple SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Answer -

```
select case
         when to_number(to_char(last_day('01-FEB-1900'), 'dd')) = 29 then
          'Leap Year'
         else
          'Non Leap Year'
       end
  from dual;
```

Comment: Hi, you seem to have asked a question in the title and then answered it. If you know the answer then why have you posted the question? Do you have a question about the SQL you have provided? If you do then what is that question?

Answer (score 0):

Just using modulus

```
select
  case mod(extract(year from sysdate),4) 
    when 0 then 'Leap'
    else 'Non leap'
  end
from dual
```

Comment: That is not the correct calculation for a leap year, there is additional logic that needs to be taken into consideration: "a year that is evenly divisible by 100 (for example, 1900) is a leap year only if it is also evenly divisible by 400"

Answer (score 0):

If an year is divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400 then it's not leap year even if it's divisible by 4. 1900 is not a leap year.

DB-FIDDLE:

Query#1

```
 SELECT 
   CASE
     WHEN MOD(1900,400) = 0 then 'Yes'
     WHEN MOD(1900,100) = 0 then 'No'
     WHEN MOD(1900,4) = 0 then 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
     END AS "Leap Year?"
 FROM dual;
```

Output:

| Leap Year? |
| --- |
| No |

Query#2

```
 SELECT 
   CASE
     WHEN MOD(2000,400) = 0 then 'Yes'
     WHEN MOD(2000,100) = 0 then 'No'
     WHEN MOD(2000,4) = 0 then 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
     END AS "Leap Year?"
 FROM dual;
```

Output:

| Leap Year? |
| --- |
| Yes |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=503c5c9d5bf0202e43d4b6766e1641c4)*

Answer (score 0):

A fun way to do this is to let Oracle do the work . . . using `on conversion error`:

```
select (case when to_date(<year> || '-02-29' default null on conversion error, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) is not null
             then 'Leap' else 'Non-leap'
        end)
from dual;
```